# JGroups ReplicatedHashMap with Partial State Transfer

Tags: java, replication, jgroups

I'm looking to extend the JGroups [ReplicatedHashMap demo](http://www.jgroups.org/demos.html) with additional functionality - the ability to support named submaps to be replicated across different instances within the same cluster.

The basic idea is that not all clients need to have a local copy of the entire hashmap, but might need to request additional chunks of the hashmap on demand.  Each client would start out with a relatively small base set of data, say, the state associated with the state id "base_data".  As they required more specialized data, they would perform a partial state transfer requesting the exact data they required; the state associated with state id "specialized_data_1".  This creates a kind of localized caching service where updates to the cache propogate to appropriate clients within the cluster.

Is this an appropriate use of Partial State Transfer with JGroups?  Is there a better way to do this?  Am I completely misunderstanding partial state transfer?  Since JGroups 3.x doesn't support partial state transfer, how could this be implemented there?  I haven't found very much documentation on partial state transfer, beyond [this](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/user-channel.html) small section in the documentation (scroll/search for "3.6.15. Partial state transfer"), so I'd appreciate any other good references you might recommend.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Partial state transfer was removed some time ago, as it was broken, see the link below for details. You could probably do this with messages. What you want to do sounds a bit like what Infinispan already provides, so you may want to take a look at their DIST mode.

http://jgroups.1086181.n5.nabble.com/Partial-state-transfer-removed-in-3-0-td3173.html